# SpringBoot2 data JPA throwing ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

I am using Spring Boot 2 for creating microservices. I have a scenario to save an entity. In entity for Id column I have added like below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(Strategy=GenerationType.Auto, generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
@Column(name="Id", insertable=false)
private Integer id;
```

Above works sometimes and it throws Primary Key Constraint Violation Exception sometimes. It is not consistent though. I am running it as two instances with different ports.

Error I get is unique constraint violated:

> ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; constraint [primary_key_cons]; nested exception is ConstraintViolationException.

Only option I have is to change the strategy to sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert some data manually? Maybe hibernate is generating id values which are already existing in db. If you can, just clear that table and test it again

Answer (score 0):

Don't use generic generator with strategy increment. It is not recommended to use in a cluster.

> increment
> generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not use in a cluster.

for more info -  [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html)

Use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` and crate a `SequenceGenerator`.

Example,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "YourSequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "YourSequence", name = "YourSequenceGenerator", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;
```